# SQL Server vs Access Database for Web: Compelling Arguments

Tags: asp.net, .net, sql-server, ms-access

I know you're think "hands down SQL Server" (as am I) but I'm finding myself in delicate situation that requires I "sell" this to my new supervisor (not a developer).

What I'm looking for are compelling arguments for non technical people and some that are "slightly" technical but don't really understand the differences.  I'm having a hard time convincing my current shop that this is not only extremely inefficient but dangerous in so many ways.  I won't be able to give them a dissertation however to convince them.  What arguments can I give them "quickly" that will make them understand how serious this could be?

Thanks!

Comment: What's the compelling argument *against* Access?  Sql server is more secure, robust, scalable - but for a small website that doesn't require these things, Access/Jet *would* work, despite most developers' obvious misgivings.  What's the scale and requirements of the project?

Comment: Is the main concern for management cost? Because SQL 2008R2 Express is free - http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23650

Comment: "You're the boss. However, I would like it on record that I recommended SQL Server"

Comment: Access is not now, and never has been, single user. Access 2010 is designed for web use. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff402351.aspx

Comment: You need to make your point quickly.  So ignore any impulses toward the general "Access is bad because ..." type stuff.  Instead focus specifically on why Access is not suitable for your use case.  For example, will the anticipated storage capacity exceed Access' 2 GB file size limit?

Comment: Access now works with office 365 and supports web publishing. As such, then the Access web database is not using jet, but is in fact using the office 365 servers. 

This is NOT a hosted solution, but is the massively scalable and different kind of setup of what we call cloud computer. And it is MOST important to distinguish between a cloud choice and that of a hosted solution which does not scale like office 365 it its cloud os.

So it not clear if this question is about using the web publishing options that Access has – it might be and thus it should not have been closed.

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal The rules of Stackoverflow say, AFAIK, that questions that lead to a debate or an extended discussion are not suitable for this particular area. Questions must have, for want of a better phrase, a single right answer.

Comment: Right, and my simple point is that often people ask should one use a local var, or a global var. In this case the question is using SQL server vs. using Access built in features for the Web. So depending on the data file sizes involved, I think that using office 365 and the Web abilities of Access is a better choice than SQL server. Seems to me the answer is to either use Access Web abilities or dump Access and use SQL server. I am not aware of other choices being given here so it does quite much seem like an either or answer here.

Answer (score 4):

It depends really. I'd suggest sql express if money is the problem though.

Also there is this:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/303528

> Microsoft Jet is not intended for use with high-stress server
>   applications, high-concurrency server applications, or 24 hours a day,
>   seven days a week server applications. This includes server
>   applications, such as Web applications, commerce applications,
>   transactional applications, and messaging server applications. For
>   these types of applications, the best solution is to switch to a true
>   client/server-based database system, such as Microsoft Data Engine
>   (MSDE) or Microsoft SQL Server. When you use Microsoft Jet in
>   high-stress applications such as Microsoft Internet Information Server
>   (IIS), you may experience any one of the following problems: Database
>   corruption Stability issues, such as IIS crashing or locking up Sudden
>   failure or persistent failure of the driver to connect to a valid
>   database that requires re-starting the IIS service

Comment: I don't believe money is remotely the problem here.  Seems to be plenty of that.  I think however that the problem is more the fact that there is no local Sys Admin so it would mean convincing them as well that this is necessary.

Comment: I am not sure that SQL Server is a good idea with no in-house technical support.

Answer (score 1):

You don't provide any info to really answer this.  what is your application all about? what load will it need to handle? how much data will it retain? what are the backup and availability requirements? etc...

if you are building a little web page for internal use only, Access may get you there.  for anything else, or for future expansion, for better tool integration, SQL Server is the right tool.  Just download the free express version and build you application. the available features and compatibility with the purchased version are worth it alone.  When you outgrow access you'll have to throw away everything and start again, with sql server express you can migrate without changing anything.